# Como mostrar processos em execução no servidor web

Tags: php, linux

bom minha duvida é o seguinte existe algum plugin em php onde posso visualizar os processos php, html etc... em execução no meu servidor, o Cpanel tem um plugin semelhante e queria saber se tem alguma maneira de obter isso.

Comment: Não sei se existe algo pronto pra isso, mas precisei fazer algo relacionado uma vez, utilizei um socket aberto solicitando execuções de  shell_exec() com os comandos que eu precisava analisar, e printava as respostas, exemplo: $pastas = shell_exec('ls -l');
echo "<pre>$pastas</pre>"; como a resposta vai ser um texto, podes  fazer um parse pra formatar a exibição, mas em servidores de hospedagem compartilhado pode encontrar algum impecilho.

Comment: Muito interessante esse script que você me passou, os processos mostrados nele são os que estão em execução atualmente ?

Comment: Tu quer verificar apenas os processos PHP, ou todos os processos rodando?

Comment: Então Mauro, todos os processos rodado nele que estão na pasta do meu site, mas se tiver só uns que mostra PHP seria bem vindo.

Comment: Tem essa thread na comunidade norte-americana. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335968/how-to-get-list-of-php-processes-running-on-server-with-php